# How can I have my IDE recognize PHP call_user_func?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

In my code I use :

```
call_user_func_array(array($foo, $bar), $methodParameters);
```

The issue is that exceptions thrown are not recognize by IDE. So I'm losing track as there are quite a few.

How can I make it so that the IDE recognize the methods that can and will be executed?

I am using PhpStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there's no way. It's this one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-52202